# How do I perform Star Schema Benchmark query concurrency test in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I perform Star Schema Benchmark to test ours DB product. I perform Star Schema Benchmark query concurrency test in jmeter.How do I set up SSB SQL to be executed concurrently in JMeter？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute [Star Schema Benchmark sample queries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/sample-queries.html#GUID-431A16E8-4C4D-4786-BE5C-30029AC1EFD8) from JMeter you will need to:

1. Copy the [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for your "DB product" to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation (or any other folder in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath))
2. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and specify:

   - your "DB product" instance [JDBC URL](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc-url-format)
   - [fully qualified class name](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/get-the-fully-qualified-name-of-a-class-in-java) of the JDBC Driver
   - credentials
   - other options like pool size, timeouts, etc.
3. Add [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler and put your query there (one query per Sampler)
4. Now increase the number of users/loops in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) according to your workload model and run your test

More information:

- [Building a Database Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)
- [How to use Different JDBC Drivers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732729-How-to-use-Different-JDBC-Drivers)

Comment: Dmitri Thanks! But I want to set all SSB query in per Sampler, and every thread will randomly execute the query from a Sampler

Comment: It won't work this way, you can put the queries into a CSV file and use [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md) so each user would pick the random query on next iteration. Random CSV Data Set Config can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)